# boost::make_shared() with templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have seen there are a lot of questions/answers regarding usage of boost's make_shared() and templated classes, but being quite new at C++ I don't seem to find what I am looking for.
So basically I have created a Class called Generic, which its manager class called GenericManager has the following public member.

```
class GenericManager
{
public:
typedef boost::shared_ptr<GeneriClass> GenericClassPtr;
//... more members etc
};
```

Now I have another class that's templated and I want to create a make_shared call, ie:

```
template <class MyType>
SpecificClass<MyType>::...
{
//class members functions etc
};
```

and then the call I want to do is:

```
GenericClassPtr SpecificClassFactory::construct()
{
    return boost::make_shared<SpecificClass>();
}
```

Which works fine for non templated version of SpecificClass but for the templated version I get the usual error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘make_shared()’
```

How could the make_shared called be alternated to accept the template type? For now I try to stick to C++98!

Edit: @wasthishelpful Fixed typo mentioned, thanks.

Comment: `return boost::make_shared<SpecificClass<YourType> >();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SpecificClass` needs a template parameter:

```
return boost::make_shared<SpecificClass<SomeType> >();
// in C++98, do not forget space here           ^^^
```

So your `construct` method should have one as well, either for the whole class:

```
template<typename SomeType>
struct SpecificClassFactory
{
    static GenericClassPtr construct()
    {
        return boost::make_shared<SpecificClass<SomeType> >();
    }
};

// usage

GenericManager::GenericClassPtr ptr = SpecificClassFactory<SomeType>::construct();
```

Or only for the method:

```
template<typename SomeType>
GenericClassPtr SpecificClassFactory::construct()
{
    return boost::make_shared<SpecificClass<SomeType> >();
}

// usage

GenericManager::GenericClassPtr ptr = SpecificClassFactory::construct<SomeType>();
```

Note that your typedef in `GenericClass` may be better outside class declaration (see [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Flat is better than nested"):

```
class GenericManager
{
public:
//... more members etc
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<GeneriClass> GenericClassPtr;
```

This will allow to call `GenericClassPtr` directly, instead of `GenericManager::GenericClassPtr`.

Comment: It works like a charm so thanks, but how can I create a MyType templated version of the GenericClassPtr SpecificClassFactory::construct(), since GenericClass is not templated? I can call return boost::make_shared<SpecificClass<double> > but not boost::make_shared<SpecificClass<MyType>. Something I am missing here? I could create a macro that has two seperate float/double variants, but that's what I am trying to avoid!

Comment: @user3616082 not sure to understand your comment. I edited my answer, tell me if it helps (or not ^^)